# $\nabla_X(AY)=A\nabla_XY$ for all vector fields $X$ and $Y$ and $A$ is constant invertible matrix.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, connections

I've been working with Riemannian manifolds $(M,g)$ of dimension $n$, with Riemannian connection $\nabla$, and I've encountered a problem that I can't seem to solve. I would appreciate any help you could provide.

Here's the scenario:

Given are two vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on the manifold, and a constant, invertible $n \times n$ matrix $A$. The Levi-Civita connection (i.e., the Riemannian connection) $\nabla$ provides a way to differentiate vector fields along other vector fields. So I understand that if we have two vector fields $X$ and $Y$, the Riemannian connection $\nabla_XY$ will give us a new vector field.

My question pertains to how this connection interacts with the multiplication of a vector field by a constant matrix.

Specifically, suppose we have a vector field $Y$ and we multiply it by a constant matrix $A$ to get $AY$. If we then apply the Riemannian connection $\nabla_X$ to this product, will the result be the same as if we first applied the connection to $Y$ and then multiplied the result by $A$?

Formally, my question is: Can we say that $\nabla_X(AY)=A\nabla_XY$ for all vector fields $X$ and $Y$ and for all constant matrices $A$?

I understand that the Riemannian connection is a local derivative operator, so intuitively, I would expect that it can be distributed over constant matrix multiplication like this, but I haven't been able to prove it, nor find a counterexample. I would be grateful if you could confirm whether this equation holds in general, and if so, could you please provide a detailed explanation or proof? If it doesn't, a counterexample would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A constant matrix doesn't act on a vector field unless you've chosen a trivialisation of the tangent bundle. Pointwise, this is the statement that an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ can act on an element $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, but it can't act on an element $v$ of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ until you choose a basis for $V$ (and therefore can express $v$ as $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$).

Comment: Here's what is true: Let $A: T_*M \rightarrow T_*M$ be a map such that $A$ restricted to each $T_pM$ is a linear map $A_p: T_pM \rightarrow T_pM$. In other words, it is a $(1,1)$-tensor field. We can call $A$ "constant" if its covariant derivative is everywhere $0$. In that case, $\nabla_X(AY) = A\nabla_XY$.